# Image uri giving invalid prop `source` supplied to `Image`

Tags: image, react-native, uri

I am a developing an Iphone App using React Native.I want to display an array of Images onto the screen.
Below is the code: Download.js

```
import React,{useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet,Text ,FlatList,ActivityIndicator,Image} from 'react-native';
import { useSelector,useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import * as downloadActions from '../../store/actions/download';

const DownloadPage = props =>{
const image = useSelector(state => state.download.availableImages);
const [isLoading,setIsLoading] = useState(false);
const dispatch = useDispatch(); 

useEffect(() => {
 const loadImage = async ()=>{
  setIsLoading(true);
   await dispatch(downloadActions.filedownload());
   setIsLoading(false);
   //setIsLoading(true);
 };
 loadImage();
  },[dispatch]);

 if(isLoading){
 return <View>
   <ActivityIndicator size='large'/>
 </View>
 }

 return(
  <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
  <FlatList
  data={ image }
  renderItem={({item}) => 
   <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
   <Image source = {{ uri: item.GCP_Image}}  style={styles.imageView} />
   </View>
 
   }

 keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
 
 />

 </View>

 )}

 const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  MainContainer :{
 
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flex:1,
    margin: 5,
    marginTop: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 20 : 0,
    backgroundColor: 'green'
  },
 
   imageView: {
 
    width: '50%',
    height: 100 ,
    margin: 7,
    borderRadius : 7
 
   },
 
   textView: {
 
    width:'50%', 
    textAlignVertical:'center',
    padding:10,
    color: '#000'
 
   }
   
   });


   export default DownloadPage;
```

By the API I have got the following array:

```
Array [
Image {
"GCP_Image": Array [
  "https://storage.googleapis.com/...../1602863214485.jpg",
  "https://storage.googleapis.com/...../0Ay3P4AVObQ8csHgAFk5.mp4",
  "https://storage.googleapis.com/...../1LNQQmtjEm4apPp4VK6u.jpg"
 ]
```

All these Images are valid urls.

If I pass array into image source with {item.GCP_Image} only first image gets displayed.When I pass this array into Image uri, I am getting the following error:
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `source` supplied to `Image`.

Can you please help me where I am going wrong.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Image `source` property takes something of type `ImageURISource` or an Array of `ImageURISource`'s. So try:

```
Array [
Image {
"GCP_Image": Array [
  {uri: "https://storage.googleapis.com/...../1602863214485.jpg"},
  {uri: "https://storage.googleapis.com/...../0Ay3P4AVObQ8csHgAFk5.mp4"},
  {uri: "https://storage.googleapis.com/...../1LNQQmtjEm4apPp4VK6u.jpg"}
 ]
```

This is an array of `ImageURISource`'s

Comment: I could sent the following API data as you said above: Array [
  Image {
    "GCP_Image": Array [
      Object {
        "uri": "https://storage.googleapis.com/...../IphoneImg-1602863214485.jpg",
      },Object {
        "uri": "https://storage.googleapis.com/...../IphoneImg-1602863214486.jpg",
      }]}]. After running this I am getting an error as: JSON value '{uri = "https://storage.googleapis.com/...../IphoneImg-1602863214485.jpg"}' of type NSMutableDictionary cannot be converted to valid URL.Got any thought of this.I am still trying...

Comment: with Image as <Image source={{uri:itemData.item.GCP_Image[0]}}/>

Comment: try `<Image source={itemData.item.GCP_Image[0]}/>`

Answer (score 0):

Since your data returned from your api has a pre-defined shape, you can provide the image array to your FlatList like below. Because GCP_Image has the actual image uris as an acceptable array.

```
 <FlatList
  data={image[0].GCP_Image} ...
/>
```

And, in your renderItem function, you need to give `item` as your source uri

```
renderItem = {({item}) => 
   <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
   <Image source = {{ uri: item}}  style={styles.imageView} />
   </View>}
```